# Unstack on two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How could I unstack this dataframes for both type and category - without creating new df and merging back on, and without creating the "apple" column using a manual sum after unstacking? Need generalisable code for a df with many fruits and categories

```
df
        area    type  sale       category         date

0     london  apple  20         green_apple      2010-01-01
1     london  apple  30         red_apple        2010-01-01
2     france  apple  40         green_apple      2010-01-01
3     london  banana 17        yellow_banana     2010-01-01
```

Expected Output

```
                          green_apple   yellow_banana    red_apple  apple       banana
london   2010-01-01           20            17              30        50          17
         ...
france   2010-01-01           40           0              0         40            0
...
```

I tried

```
df.set_index(['date', 'area', 'type', 'category'])['sale'].unstack()
```

Comment: Looks like a job for pivot tables: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the standard `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(columns = ['type','category'], values = 'sale', index = ['area','date'])
```

but it gives you a multi-index table that does not look quite like what you want:

```
    type            apple                   banana
category            green_apple red_apple   yellow_banana
area    date            
france  2010-01-01  40.0        NaN         NaN
london  2010-01-01  20.0        30.0        17.0
```

One solution is to do two `pivot_table`s separately and munge them together -- note the `aggfunc` we need to use for 'type' (and let's use for 'category' just in case)

```
(df.pivot_table(columns = ['type'], values = 'sale', index = ['area','date'], aggfunc = 'sum')
   .join(
       df.pivot_table(columns = ['category'], values = 'sale', index = ['area','date'], aggfunc = 'sum')
   )
   .fillna(0)
)
```

to get

```
                    apple   banana  green_apple red_apple   yellow_banana
area    date                    
france  2010-01-01  40.0    0.0     40.0        0.0         0.0
london  2010-01-01  50.0    17.0    20.0        30.0        17.0
```

### edit: solution with a single `pivot_table`

... but with an extra `melt`

```
(df.melt(id_vars = ['area', 'date', 'sale'], value_vars = ['type','category'] )
   .pivot_table(columns = ['value'], values = 'sale', index = ['area','date'], aggfunc = 'sum')
   .fillna(0)
)
```

Comment: Is there a way without merging?

Comment: @asd just thought of another way without merging, check out the edit